# Can you forbid local instantiation of a class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, scope, instantiation

I have a helper class for autonomous process monitoring, and as it's a bit a "fire and forget" mechanism, a big pitfall is that you can use it like this:

> MyClass c(process);

But when c goes out of scope, the thread inside stops and no notifications, obviously, comes out from it.

How you should do it is like this:

> MyClass *c=new MyClass(process);

and handle the lifetime yourself.

Is there an easy, good way, to forbid a local instantiation and only allow "new" in c++ ?

Cheers!

Valmond

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the destructor of the class private (and define an alternative member function for deallocation). This forbids any direct stack instantiations of the class, allowing only heap (`new`) instantiations.

NOTE: this is better than making constructors private, because objects can still be created directly rather than through a function. Also there is only one destructor that needs to be privatised, but there could be many constructors.

To do the delete, you can implement something like:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    void free()
    {
        delete this;
    }

private:
    ~MyStruct() {};

};

int main()
{
    MyStruct* s = new MyStruct;
    s->free();
}
```

Comment: Another possible solution (except declaring private constructor or destructor methods) is usage of smart pointers by declaring own type like this: 

typedef std::unique_ptr<MyClass> PtrMyClass;

But it is not elegant way.

Comment: Okay so I call my destructor through a public member function, but how do I do the delete?

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot, I just do a delete(this) in the public member function, cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could make the constructor private and then allow instantiation through a friend function, which always does it through new

Answer (score 3):

"How you should do it ... `new MyClass`." No, that is not how you should do it. That's asking for memory leaks.

The better way is to have

```
class MyClass {
  MyClass(Process const&);
public:
  static std::unique_ptr<MyClass> make(Process const&);
}
```

This indeed prevents callers from writing `MyClass c {process};`.

Of course, neither your idea for `new MyClass` nor this idea is an absolute prevention. Both pointers would have to be stored somewhere. Storing either in a function-local `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>` causes the same exact problem as you originally had.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but your implementation limits the use of several instantiations, am I right ?

Comment: @Valmond: No, not at all? In fact, if there would be a single instantiation, then we can't return a `std::unique_ptr<T>`. Because if we call `MyClass::make() ` twice, we get two `unique_ptr` that obviously wouldn't be unique if they pointed to a single instantiation.

Comment: @MrSalters Okay, thanks for clearing up my misunderstanding!